# replace comma(,) only if its inside quotes("") in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have data like this:

```
1,234,"john, lee", john@xyz.com
```

I want to remove , inside "" with space using pig script. So that my data will look like:

```
1,234,john lee, john@xyz.com
```

I tried using CSVExcelStorage to load this data but i need to use '-tagFile' option as well which is not supported in CSVExcelStorage . So i am planning to use PigStorage only and then replace any comma (,) inside quotes.
I am stuck on this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the perfect way to do this. A very generic solution is as below:

```
data = LOAD 'data.csv' using PigStorage(',','-tagFile') AS (filename:chararray, record:chararray);

/*replace comma(,) if it appears in column content*/
replaceComma = FOREACH data GENERATE filename, REPLACE (record, ',(?!(([^\\"]*\\"){2})*[^\\"]*$)', '');

/*replace the quotes("") which is present around the column if it have comma(,) as its a csv file feature*/
replaceQuotes = FOREACH replaceComma GENERATE filename, REPLACE ($4,'"','') as record;
```

Detailed use case is available at [my blog](http://www.bigjavaspace.com/app/article/read/Pig_Tips_and_Tricks_Part1)

Answer (score 1):

Below command will help:

```
csvFile = load '/path/to/file' using PigStorage(',');
result = foreach csvFile generate $0 as (field1:chararray),$1 as (field2:chararray),CONCAT(REPLACE($2, '\\"', '') , REPLACE($3, '\\"', '')) as field3,$4 as (field4:chararray);
```

Ouput:

> (1,234,john lee, john@xyz.com)

Comment: Actually comma(,) can occur in any field and the field count is more than 30. So i don't want to do concat or replace those many time

Comment: have u tried csv loader ?http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html

Answer (score 0):

Load it into a single field and then use STRSPLIT and REPLACE

```
A = LOAD 'data.csv' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT(line,'\\"',3); 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE REPLACE($1,',','');
D = FOREACH C GENERATE CONCAT(CONCAT($0,$1),$2); -- You can further use STRSPLIT to get individual fields or just CONCAT
E = FOREACH D GENERATE STRSPLIT(D.$0,',',4);
DUMP E;
```

**A**

```
1,234,"john, lee", john@xyz.com
```

**B**

```
(1,234,)(john, lee)(, john@xyz.com)
```

**C**

```
(1,234,)(john lee)(, john@xyz.com)
```

**D**

```
(1,234,john lee, john@xyz.com)
```

**E**

```
(1),(234),(john lee),(john@xyz.com)
```